# Comparing models of discrete and continuous data

Tags: time-series, mixed-type-data

I have a data-analysis problem with two closely-related timeseries. Both are binned in time at the same rate, but one is discrete (takes values in $\mathbb{Z}$), and the other is continuous. I am interested in modeling each of these processes' dependence on a common set of predictors, $X$.

Given $X$, the question I would like to answer is,

> "How well can I predict the discrete series from $X$, compared to my ability to
> predict the continuous timeseries from $X$ (and visa versa)?"

I'd be interested in knowing if there's any standard way of addressing this problem, or if I should just avoid comparing prediction performance.  What I've looked at so far is log-likelihood - a Gaussian log-likelihood for the continuous data, and Poisson for the discrete data. This leads me to another question, the answer to which I suspect to be false (but it's not obvious to me),

> "Is it meaningful to compare log-likelihoods from different models? If so, in
> what cases?"

Hopefully I've left enough details for a meaningful response.

Comment: Interesting problem. Could you discretise the continuous domain and there for treat both problems as discrete? Otherwise you're right, you cannot compare log-likelihoods. In order to compare the evidence of two models you need to supply them both with the same data.

Comment: For likelihoods to be comparable tey need to be defined with respectto the same dominating measure. So discrete and continuous --- not